# How to follow link of element with a certain id in rvest?

Tags: r, web-scraping, data-science, rvest

I'm current scaping this site:

https://uws-community.symplicity.com/index.php?s=student_group

so each club on the site has a certain id, an also has a "more info" link. I've already found a way to scrape each id from the div.grpl-grp.clearfix class, but I would like to use the IDs to scrape data from the "more info" link (such as the fb link) from an element with that certain id.

What's the syntax to go about doing that?

Answer (score 1):

The "More Information" text has got class "grpl-moreinfo" and the link is in the `<a>` tag. So we can do

```
library(rvest)

url <- 'https://uws-community.symplicity.com/index.php?s=student_group'
page <- html_session(url)
html_nodes(page, "li.grpl-moreinfo a") %>% html_attr("href")

#[1] "?mode=form&id=5bf9ea61bc46eaeff075cf8043c27c92&tab=profile"
#[2] "?mode=form&id=17e4ea613be85fe019efcf728fb6361d&tab=profile"
#[3] "?mode=form&id=d593eb48fe26d58f616515366a1e677b&tab=profile"
...
```

---

Which can also be done in one chain operation as:

```
url %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_nodes("li.grpl-moreinfo a") %>%
  html_attr("href")

#[1] "?mode=form&id=5bf9ea61bc46eaeff075cf8043c27c92&tab=profile"
#[2] "?mode=form&id=17e4ea613be85fe019efcf728fb6361d&tab=profile"
#[3] "?mode=form&id=d593eb48fe26d58f616515366a1e677b&tab=profile"
...
```